# Travel insurance with a pre-existing condition

Tags: uk, health, insurance

I have ulcerative collitis. It's not particularly bad. I'm trying to get travel insurance for two different holidays (one to the US and one to China/Japan). Unfortunately having ulcerative collitis means that a lot of companies either won't cover me or want to charge me the earth for cover.

Could someone recommend a UK-based insurer that does reasonable rates for people with pre-existing medical conditions?

Comment: Are you talking about trip insurance that refunds you if you cancel the trip, or health insurance which covers your medical needs while you are abroad?

Comment: Health insurance, but if it has cancellation insurance, that would be great

Comment: Do you need the insurance to cover the Ulcerative Collitis, or are you happy to take one that covers everything else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end I ended up using a UK based company called Medici travel who gave me a very reasonable rate for annual travel insurance.

Turns out that my health insurance policy would have covered me anyway for ulcerative collitis abroad, and I could have just got regular travel insurance.

It's definitely worth checking if you have health insurance if your policy covers you while overseas as it would have saved me a packet if I'd known that.

Comment: Interesting. I"ll look into them as well, as I need another policy for some more travel coming up.  Thanks for posting your final solution!

Comment: No Problem. Obviously it has to be a health insurance policy that covers your medical condition

Comment: I went on a long trip last year (9 months), still with a preexisiting condition. Used StaySure Backpacker insurance.

Answer (score 6):

I have a rare but serious heart condition that also tends to freak out insurance companies.  However, I've found that if I get a letter from my cardiologist and my GP saying that there's no reason to expect anything to go wrong for period x-x, they're happy to either insure me, or to insure if I pay a premium.

When I was in NZ, Mike Henry Travel Insurance would do this, as well as Southern Cross travel insurance.  They may have international branches?

For my current trip, I'm actually with World Nomads, although I don't think they're UK based.

Good luck - there's always a way, often your doctor might be able to suggest a company as well, or write extra documentation about it.  He may offer to say that if you agree to carry medicine x or y with you they'll reduce the premium, or something - there's usually some way to do it, even if it's a high premium.