# Does the ACA provision about pre-existing conditions apply to visitors to the US?

Tags: usa, insurance

[Travel insurance with a pre-existing condition](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/805/travel-insurance-with-a-pre-existing-condition) does not mention ACA--not surprising since it was posted in 2011.

I know that the Affordable Care Act stopped payers from considering pre-existing conditions.  But perhaps that prohibition only applies when the subscriber is a U.S. citizen.

I have a Canadian friend who received a $3000 per MONTH quote, and she thinks a pre-existing condition might explain it.

Comment: Wouldn't you typically get travel insurance from your place of residence?

Comment: could you indicate why you think the person would be covered by ACA?

Comment: The ACA has nothing to do with visitors to the US.

Comment: @DJClayworth: sounds a lot like an answer.  You think it's worth elaborating and posting as one?  If she is buying from a U.S. company, that company might have to comply with ACA.  And if that is the case, then she might be better off buying from a U.S. company.

Comment: @WGroleau the ACA is not travel insurance, it's for residents only (and maybe even only for citizens, I've not approved it so I can't know what's in it).

Comment: @DJClayworth: That is wrong. ACA has to do with lawfully present nonimmigrants too.

Comment: @user102008 The phrase is " lawfully present permanent residents", which excludes tourists.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Nope, you got it wrong. It is anyone who is lawfully present, including tourists, as long as they are resident alien for tax purposes.

Comment: My point is that tourists are NOT usually resident aliens for tax purposes. If they are there for more six months (the usual cutoff to become resident for tax purposes) or working (the other usual criterion) they are not usually considered tourists.

Answer (score 1):

ACA/Obamacare does not apply to tourists.  [The best explanation I've found](http://www.visitorscoverage.com/how-does-obamacare-affect-visitors-to-usa/) (disclaimer: it's from an insurance reseller):

> Visitors to the USA do not have access to health care while in the USA
>   for the simple fact that they are not U.S. citizens. Even if you have
>   family - perhaps a son or daughter, or parents - who are U.S.
>   citizens, every visitor to America is considered a tourist and medical
>   care for tourists is not free.
>
> Only U.S. citizens and certain lawfully presented permanent residents
>   (green card holders) qualify for federal health insurance program also
>   known as Affordable Care Act or Obama Care in the US and visitors to
>   the U.S. are responsible for paying for their own medical care.

However the US government's site backs this up, with travellers and tourists nowhere to be found in [their list of persons that qualify for coverage](https://www.healthcare.gov/immigration-status-and-the-marketplace/).

Comment: That site's phrasing is not the best. *Health care* is absolutely available to visitors from hospitals, urgent care centers, clinics, pharmacies, individual practitioners, and so on. *Health insurance* or any other domestic medical payment schemes are not, so all health-related expenses incurred must be settled out of pocket or with travel medical insurance. We don't want to visitors to think they will be left dying in the street. :)

Comment: Also, I didn't ask whether they qualify to buy ACA federal coverage. The question was whether the payer they buy from is subject to the prohibition against considering pre-existing conditions. Anyway, they did finally find a much more reasonable price.

Comment: This answer is not correct. ACA does not only apply to U.S. citizens and permanent residents. It also applies to people in lawful nonimmigrant status (including tourists, students, foreign workers, etc.) who are resident aliens for tax purposes. The determination of who is a resident alien is complicated, but generally anyone present in the U.S. for more than 183 days in the year is a resident alien.

Comment: @user102008 Pretty much by definition if you are a resident you are not a tourist.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Not true. The definition of resident alien is anyone whose (# of days in the U.S. this year + 1/3 of # of days in the U.S. last year + 1/6 of # of days in the U.S. the year before that) is at least 183 days.